# How to create tui-calendar creation pop-up in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating [Customize Popup](https://github.com/nhn/tui.calendar/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#customize-popups) for my application using [tui-calendar](https://github.com/nhn/toast-ui.react-calendar)

this is my code:

```js
    const onBeforeCreateSchedule = useCallback(data => {
        setScheduleData({
            start: data.start.toDate(),
            end: data.end.toDate(),
        });
        setCreateScheduleModalVisible(true);
        console.log(newSchedule);
 props.calendarRef.current.calendarInst.createSchedules([newSchedule]);
    }, [newSchedule, props.calendarRef]);
```

I just need start and end time for my pop-up to create schedule. `scheduleData` will pass as props to pop-up component.

How can I make `createSchedules()` method waiting for pop-up return `newSchedule` to create new schedule? this time `console.log(newSchedule);` will return null;

Thanks & Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using hooks, you could just add a separate `useEffect` on `newSchedule` that makes the call to `createSchedules`. And remove the logic from the callback.

This runs every time `newSchedule` changes regardless of the value so you may need some conditional logic here.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  props.calendarRef.current.calendarInst.createSchedules([newSchedule]);
}, [newSchedule])
```